# How to aggs on particular field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have dictionary below

```
  {
    'id': 0,
    'Title': 'Wolf',
    'Major Genre': Action,
    'IMDB': "7"
  },
  {
    'id': 1,
    'Title': 'The Land Girls',
    'Major Genre': Drama,
    'IMDB': "7"
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'Title': 'Beauty',
    'Major Genre': Comedy,
    'IMDB': "5"
  }
```

1. Need to find the aggregation function for `Major Genre`
2. Need to filter the output which is having `Major Genre` == `Comedy` which IMDB >6

I have done below and i got error

```
{
   "size": 100,
   "aggregations": {
         "terms": {
            "Major Genre": "Comedy"
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Please share the error.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'aggs' instead of 'aggregations'?

Comment: not sure I understood your goal: do you want to apply a filter to a search, or do you want to aggregate over a filtered search? Can you tell us what response you would like to get from Elasticsearch?

Comment: @glenacota I need aggs function

Comment: @Nons did the answer I posted solve your problem? Please mark it as correct if it did or let me know if you have any questions about.

Comment: No becuase, aggregration function has to give all the Major_genre, like Drama:1, Action:1, Comedy:1

Comment: Then you can remove the `query` field from @llermaly's answer, and leave only the `aggs` field. Maybe you can add a `"size": 0` field before or after `aggs`, to include only the aggregated values in the response

Comment: @Nons you condition #2 says to filter output by genre and IMDB score. There is no way to filter by Comedy and aggregate all genres with 1 query, you will have to do 2 queries for that (one match_all for the aggregations, and another one with filters for the output documents)

Comment: @llermaly, Okay, can you split into 2 queries and answer?

Comment: @Nons I edited my answer with the splitted queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: splitted queries

Filtering documents by Comedy genre

```
POST test_nons/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "IMDB": {
              "gte": 4
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "Major Genre.keyword": "Comedy"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Getting all possible genres

```
POST test_nons/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "major_genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Major Genre.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Ingest data**

```
POST test_nons/_doc
{
  "id": 0,
  "Title": "Wolf",
  "Major Genre": "Action",
  "IMDB": "7"
}
  
POST test_nons/_doc
{
  "id": 1,
  "Title": "The Land Girls",
  "Major Genre": "Drama",
  "IMDB": "7"
}
  
POST test_nons/_doc
{
  "id": 2,
  "Title": "Beauty",
  "Major Genre": "Comedy",
  "IMDB": "5"
}
```

**Request**

```
POST test_nons/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "IMDB": {
              "gte": 6
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "Major Genre.keyword": "Comedy"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "major_genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Major Genre.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

There are no docs with Comedy genre and IMBD > 6 so response would be empty.

For example purposes I will filter by IMDB > 4 instead of 6 to have some data in the response.

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_nons",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Rcd06ncB50NMsuQPeVRj",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2,
          "Title" : "Beauty",
          "Major Genre" : "Comedy",
          "IMDB" : "5"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "major_genres" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Comedy",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```